# Haskell Yesod how to controll how Persistent will access the DB columns

Tags: haskell, yesod

I have a database which is already quite big, and I need to access the tables and the columns the way they have been written THERE (camelCase). Can I change the following code to make it possible to access camelCase, or at least a way to define a String as it is in my database, for each table and column?

```
share [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"]
  $(persistFileWith lowerCaseSettings "config/models")
```

Another thing: I don't want to do any migration, I want just to do the CRUD

**Example**

Model:

```
MyTest
  firstName Text
```

Table:

```
create table MyTest ( 
  id int unsigned AUTO_INCREMENT,
  firstName varchar (255) not null, 
  primary key(id)
)
```

Another thing: What if I have a column called myColumn2 and I want it to be myColumn in the definition? How could I define a custom name to be used while talking to the DB?

Comment: can you please show some of your tables definition and the `models` file? I have a hard time trying to figure out what you are asking here

Comment: As Carsten told, without the models file, it would be hard to help you. If you don't want to do migration, just remove the `runMigration migrateAll` code.

Comment: there is a nice [tutorial](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/school/advanced-haskell/persistent-in-detail/existing-database) on how to do this (remap column-names) - you basically write `myColumn int sql=myColumn2`

Answer (score 1):

Look at this page in the docs: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent-2.2.2/docs/Database-Persist-Quasi.html

The field named psToDBName can be set to give you the behavior you are looking for. I'm on a phone right now, but I'll try to give an example later when I get back to a computer.